Google Sheets: Apply lower() to an entire range of values?
Is it possible to apply the lower() function to an entire range of values in Google Sheets?
For example, columns A:D.

Use an arrayformula() wrapper to evaluate a formula over a range of cells rather than a single cell. An array formula will return multiple results automatically.
Note that spreadsheet formulas cannot change values in existing cells. They give new values in new cells based on existing ones.
To get the contents of columns A1:D in lowercase in columns E1:H, clear columns E1:H and put this formula in cell E1:
=arrayformula(lower(A1:D))

